# Helicoid in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, differential-topology, analytic-geometry

I'm considering a parametric equation of helicoid in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $X(u,v)=(u \cos v, u \sin v,v,v).$
Now I can calculate two unit tangent vectors $t_1=\dfrac{X_u}{\vert X_u\vert}=(\cos u, \sin u, 0,0) $ and
$t_2=\dfrac{X_v}{\vert X_v \vert}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+2}}(-u \sin v, u \cos v, 1, 1)$. The problem is how to find 2 unit normal vectors $n_1, n_2$? I tried and find that $n_1= \dfrac{(0,0,1.-1)}{\sqrt{2}}$ is ok, but the second unit normal vector is more difficult.

Comment: Take a general vector field $n_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and then impose the three equations given by orthogonality with $X_u,X_v$ and $n_1$

Comment: Note you have a typo in $t_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is just "the usual" helicoid sitting in the hyperplane $x_3=x_4$. The normal vector you found is the normal vector to that hyperplane. If you review the computation for "the usual" helicoid in $\Bbb R^3$, you have the (non-unit length) normal $(\sin v,-\cos v, u)$. So you might guess the vector $(\sin v,-\cos v, u/2, u/2)$. Note that this is orthogonal to both $t_j$ and to $n_1$.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I computed wrong the vector $t_1$ so it leads to difficult to find the second vector $n_2$ in normal space. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. If you’re satisfied, you should accept the answer. If you have questions to follow up with, of course do so.